# to keep in your account

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

**At a Bank**

**Woman**: Hi. I’d like to open a saving account.

**Teller**: OK. What type of balance, how much money do you intend to **keep** in your account?

**Woman**: Probably less than a 1000  dollars.

---

What does "to **keep** in your account" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it simply means "What account balance do you intend to have?" or "how much money will usually be in the account." It could be used to indicate a minimum balance, a sum that  the account will not fall below. It is not clear that that sense is intended here.

"Keep" here means "retain" or "store". It may or may not carry the further implication of "permanently".

The question "how much money do you intend to keep" is about her future intentions, that is, what will she typically have in the account after she opens it. (that is why it uses a future form) This is because different accounts have different fee structures, and some work better for smaller balances.

---

By the way "Probably less than a 1000 dollars." is unnatural in writing. The usual forms would be:

- > Probably less than a thousand dollars.

> - Probably less than 1,000 dollars.

In spoken English this is not so apparant.

Comment: What does "keep" mean individually in this sentence?

Comment: @rezaellstack I have responded by editing the answer.

Comment: I don't think it will mean 'retain' because that woman is opening her bank account.

Comment: @lee But it's a savings account, so she will keep the money there until she needs it.

Comment: _"Retain - continue to hold/have/possess something"_ I understand, she'll keep the money there until she needs it. But she doesn't have any money in her account (or better to say she doesn't even have an account). So how can she retain the money that she has not deposited.

Comment: @lee  The question "how much money do you intend to keep" is about her **future** intentions, that is, what will she typically have in the account after she opens it. (that is why it uses a future form) This is because different accounts have different fee structures, and some work better for smaller balances.